# Get Desktop directory OS-independent

Tags: java, cross-platform, desktop

Of course I could use

```
File desktop = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop"));
```

but this would only work OS-independent if the OS is set to English locale...
On Windows the Desktop is named Desktop in every language it was translated to, but e.g. on Ubuntu the Desktop name gets translated (On my German system it's *Arbeitsfläche*).

So I'm looking for an OS- and Locale-independent way of getting a File object representing the desktop directory.

Comment: Did you know that not every OS has a "Desktop"?

Comment: And further you shouldn't use that constructor for file - use the two args constructor rather than concatenating with a slash.

Comment: No I didn't. I thought every OS with a graphical environment had a desktop... But after you told me it seems logical.

Comment: @BoristheSpider what's the difference?